# StyleCop Analyzers rule SA1515 violation output only in Output Window but not in Error List Window

Tags: c#, roslyn-code-analysis

I have installed StyleCop.Analyzers nuget (it's version 1.0.0) and I have configured SA1515 (Single comments must be preceded by blank line) to error on violation.

The following code however

```
namespace ConsoleApplication6
{
  class Program
  {
     static void Main(string[] args)
     {
       int x = 2;
       /// my comment
       int y = 3;
     }
  }
}
```

does only show the violation in the Ouput Window as

```
ConsoleApplication6\Program.cs(8,7,8,9): error SA1515: Single-line comment must be preceded by blank linelists the error
```

but there are no squiggles and no entries in the Error Window. Changing the `///` to `//` makes the error appear in the error list immediately.

Is there are way to debug this in order to find the buggy spot? I have opened the source code I got from GitHub in Visual Studio, set a break point on the one `context.ReportDiagnostic` call in that rule class, set to start another VS instance on debug start, opened the ConsoleApplication6 in there and never got a break point hit.

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the `<warningLevel>`-Tag in the csproj. The error should appear in the error list.